# ListView with only 1 column is not filling the whole width

Tags: winforms

I have a list view that gets populated dynamically each time a new message comes in. I did not add a column to the collection in the designer since I only need 1 column. But when the new message comes in, the "listview" gets populated but the single column is not taking the whole width of the listview.

```
lvRfidMessages.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
lvRfidMessages.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
string[] rowData = { e };
var lvItem = new ListViewItem(rowData);
lvRfidMessages.Items.Add(lvItem);
```

[image]

The design

```
this.lvRfidMessages.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DimGray;
            this.lvRfidMessages.FullRowSelect = true;
            this.lvRfidMessages.GridLines = true;
            this.lvRfidMessages.HeaderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeaderStyle.Nonclickable;
            this.lvRfidMessages.HideSelection = false;
            this.lvRfidMessages.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 64);
            this.lvRfidMessages.Name = "lvRfidMessages";
            this.lvRfidMessages.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(182, 185);
            this.lvRfidMessages.TabIndex = 3;
            this.lvRfidMessages.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
```

Comment: You have set `GridLines = true`, but it appears the `View` remains set to the default `LargeIcon`. You may want to set the `View` to `List`, but the grid lines won't show up.

Comment: BTW, not clear what `AutoResizeColumns()` is for, since it appears you don't have any columns.

Comment: @Jimi "BTW, not clear what AutoResizeColumns().." I was actually putting in everything just so I can get what I really wanted. Apparently it doesn't work too.

Comment: Well, if you don't add Columns then that method doesn't work for sure. As mentioned, you need to set the `View` to `List` if you don't have Columns. Or `Details`, if you add one.